# optional closure and check if it is nil

Tags: swift, closures, block

So what I want to have is a class that may get a closure passed to it in a function, it may also at some point want to disregard a that closure. How can I check if the closure variable is set and hwo can I delete it when I am done with it?

> Cannot invoke '!=' with an argument list of type '(@lvalue (sucsess:
>   Bool!, products: [AnyObject]!) -> ()?, NilLiteralConvertible)' Type
>   '(sucsess: Bool!, products: [AnyObject]!) -> ()?' does not conform to
>   protocol 'NilLiteralConvertible'

```
class someClass{
    //typealias completionHandlerClosureType = (sucsess:Bool!, items:[AnyObject]!)->()
    var completionHandler:(sucsess:Bool!, items:[AnyObject]!)->()?
    var hitpoints = 100
    var someset = ["oh no!","avenge me!"]
    init(){}

    func getHitFunc(impact:Int, passedCompletionsHandler:(sucsess:Bool!, items:[AnyObject]!)->()){
        completionHandler = passedCompletionsHandler
        hitpoints = hitpoints - impact
    }

    func checkIfDead{
        if hitpoints<=0 {               // The error received
            if completionHandler != nil{// Cannot invoke '!=' with an argument list of type 
                                        //'(@lvalue (sucsess: Bool!, products: [AnyObject]!) -> ()?, NilLiteralConvertible)' 
                //run the handler if dead
                completionHandler(sucsess: true, items: someset)
                //do not run it again
                completionHandler = nil     //Type '(sucsess: Bool!, products: [AnyObject]!) -> ()?' does not conform to protocol 'NilLiteralConvertible'
            }
        }
        else{
            completionHandler = nil      //Type '(sucsess: Bool!, products: [AnyObject]!) -> ()?' does not conform to protocol 'NilLiteralConvertible'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You need to wrap your closure signature in parentheses to make the closure itself optional. The way it's written now, the closure returns an optional Void (which doesn't really make sense).

```
var completionHandler: ((sucsess:Bool!, items:[AnyObject]!)->())?
```

Some style points and revisions to your example code:

```
 // Capitalize class names so it's clear what's a class 
class SomeClass {
    // "success" has two "c"s
    var completionHandler: ((success:Bool!, items:[AnyObject]!)->())?
    var hitpoints = 100
    var someset = ["oh no!","avenge me!"]

    init() { }

    func getHitFunc(impact:Int, passedCompletionsHandler:(success:Bool!, items:[AnyObject]!)->()){
        completionHandler = passedCompletionsHandler
        hitpoints = hitpoints - impact
    }

    // You were missing the argument list here:
    func checkIfDead() {
        if hitpoints <= 0 {

            // Rather than checking to see if the completion handler exists, you can
            // just call it using optional syntax like this:
            completionHandler?(success: true, items: someset)
        }
        completionHandler = nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 47):

First, in your declaration of the completion handler, you need to declare the whole thing as optional with the use of parentheses:

```
var completionHandler: ((_ success: Bool, _ items: [Any]?) -> ())?
```

Or, perhaps better, you can replace that final `()` with `Void`:

```
var completionHandler: ((_ success: Bool, _ items: [Any]?) -> Void)?
```

Also, note, I don't think you meant to make the `Bool` optional (because if the closure exists, you presumably always pass a `success` value of `true` or `false`). Clearly, the array of `items` might well be optional.

Anyway, when done, you'd just make sure to unwrap that optional:

```
func checkIfDead() {
    if hitpoints <= 0 {
        completionHandler?(true, items)
    }
    completionHandler = nil
}
```

This performs the closure if and only if it is not `nil`, avoiding the need to explicitly check if it was `nil`.

---

For what it's worth, this might be a case where your `typealias` might make this less confusing:

```
typealias CompletionHandlerClosureType = (_ success: Bool, _ items: [Any]?) -> Void
```

Then the property is simply:

```
var completionHandler: CompletionHandlerClosureType?
```

The function that takes this `completionHandler` as a optional parameter could do:

```
func startSomeProcess(passedCompletionHandler: CompletionHandlerClosureType?) {
    completionHandler = passedCompletionHandler
    // do whatever else you want
}
```

and then the final completion logic is unchanged:

```
func finishSomeProcess() {
    completionHandler?(true, items)
    completionHandler = nil
}
```

---

(Note, the above has been modified for Swift 3. Please see [previous revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26128948/6) of this answer if you want to see Swift 2 renditions.)

Comment: the type alias is great solution

Comment: This is fantastic in explanation.  Still applicable to Swift 4.  Completion blocks are much improved in swift over objective-C but still can take some hand wringing to get it right, especially as I am porting over the last few objective-C classes that someone thoughtfully left in neglect for years in this project.